How Text Adornment to idml
I am studying the SDK example—BasicTextAdornment, and I have a question. It seems that it cannot store relevant information in the exported IDML file. If I want to make it save the relevant information in the exported IDML file, how should I adjust it?
kTARubyXXXBoss are all TextAdornments. Why can this data be saved to IDML, and how can this data be converted back when opening the IDML? I am not very familiar with how TextAdornment works and feel confused.
To save the relevant information in the exported IDML file
For example, below is an image showing text with an underline.
text with an underline
If I export this document as an IDML file and unzip it, I will find the relevant information about the underlined text in the related files.
    <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Character Style 1" Underline="true">
            <Content>os mant ommorti licatum mod scepostui iam et L. Ce publist issestre, vivigilis et; num abis es? Opiorum</Content>
        </CharacterStyleRange>

What I know is that the plugin must be set with the relevant script information to achieve this function, but I don't know how to set up a script for Text Adornment.
In the examples provided by the SDK, the BasicPersistInterface example clearly shows the stored label information in the IDML.(information is at the end of the tag)
BasicPersistInterface example
<Rectangle Self="u12b" ContentType="Unassigned" StoryTitle="$ID/" ParentInterfaceChangeCount="" TargetInterfaceChangeCount="" LastUpdatedInterfaceChangeCount="" OverriddenPageItemProps="" HorizontalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" VerticalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" FillColor="Color/Black" StrokeWeight="0" StrokeColor="Swatch/None" GradientFillStart="0 0" GradientFillLength="0" GradientFillAngle="0" GradientStrokeStart="0 0" GradientStrokeLength="0" GradientStrokeAngle="0" ItemLayer="ue7" Locked="false" LocalDisplaySetting="Default" GradientFillHiliteLength="0" GradientFillHiliteAngle="0" GradientStrokeHiliteLength="0" GradientStrokeHiliteAngle="0" AppliedObjectStyle="ObjectStyle/$ID/[Normal Graphics Frame]" Visible="true" Name="$ID/" ItemTransform="1 0 0 1 0 0" ***FramelabelString="" FramelabelSize="12" FramelabelVisibility="false" FramelabelPosition="FramelabelBottom" BpiData="hello"***>         

However, in the basictextadornment example, the saved IDML loses the relevant label information.

Can you maybe show an example of the expected behaviour and what currently happens? What, exactly, is "the relevant information" you are talking about?

Many people think of IDML as a means to cleanse a layout of impure third-party elements. I'm not sure you'll find a way to preserve your custom data. However, the last time I looked into this, I learned that script labels are preserved. In some use cases, InDesign XML tags and attributes can be used.
